# How to know if the pseudoscalar Yukawa Lagrangian is invariant under chiral transformation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, chirality

The pseudo-scalar Yukawa theory Lagrangian is

$$\mathcal{L}=\bar{\psi}(i\gamma ^\mu \partial_\mu - m)\psi -g\bar{\psi}i\gamma^5\phi\psi,$$ where $g$ is a coupling constant. How can I show it is invariant under a chiral transformation, $\psi\to e^{i\lambda \gamma_5}\psi$?

Comment: Um...plug the transformation in and see what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(This is a largely a response prompted by your comment.)*

You can get the answer by just remembering the commutation/anti-commutation properties of the $\gamma$ matrices, and the fact that ${\bar \psi} = \psi^{\dagger} \gamma^0$. To see the following, you would have to expand the exponential factor, up to linear order $e^{M} = I + M + \ldots$.

(I'm not going to do your homework, this is just a guide!)

1) The kinematic term $i \bar{\psi}\gamma ^\mu \partial_\mu\psi$ goes into itself, using $
\{\gamma^{\mu}, \gamma^5\} = 0$.

2) The Yukawa coupling term follows suite.

3) There is no such cancellation in the mass term $m \bar \psi \psi$, but the two factors reinforce each other. This term picks up an overall factor of $e^{2i\lambda \gamma_5}\psi$, i.e. two times either factor. Thus, the mass term is not invariant under this transformation, and breaks chiral symmetry.

B.T.W. This transformation is called the axial-vector transformation, since the corresponding conserved (in the m=0 limit) Noether current transforms like an axialvector $\bar \psi \gamma^{\mu} \gamma^5 \psi$.

Resolving into Weyl spinors $\psi_{L,R} = (1\mp \gamma^5)\psi/2$ is an alternative way of seeing this. With this, you will again have to use the $\gamma$ matrices' properties, and you will arrive at the result that only the mass term mixes up the two chiralities, i.e. becomes $m (\bar \psi_L \psi_R + \bar \psi_R \psi_L)$. The kinematic term would transform into $i \bar{\psi_L}\gamma ^\mu \partial_\mu\psi_L + i \bar{\psi_R}\gamma ^\mu \partial_\mu\psi_R$ and hence, it is like the the kinematic terms of two independent Lagrangians added up. No  mixing. The two formulations are absolutely equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your very clear guidance. I have a question though, while I am performing this transformation on Yukawa coupling term: I get the following:$$L'=-g\bar{\psi}i\gamma^5\phi\psi = -gi\bar{\psi}e^{i\lambda \gamma^5}\gamma^5 \phi e^{i\lambda\gamma^5}\psi$$ Why aren't the exponentials cancelling so it would be invariant..

Comment: As far as I know, this Lagrangian is invariant under the chiral transformation **only** if $m=0$. Am I wrong?

Comment: No absolutely right. But what to do with L' in the comment I wrote above. Does it make sense to say that as you exchange the position of $$\gamma^5$$ to the left of the exponential, you pick up a minus sign?  @Hindsight

Comment: In one of your exponentials there should be a minus sign, because $\bar{\psi}$ is a conjugate of $\psi$. Also, $\gamma^5$ commutes with its exponential (because it commutes with all terms in its Tailor expansion). So the two exponentials cancel each other.

Comment: As @New_new_newbie mentoned above, the fact that $${\{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^5}\} =0$$ will result in the negative sign in the exponential as you move $$\gamma^\mu$$ to the left. But is it the case when you move $$\gamma^5$$ ? I mean is $$\{\gamma^5,\gamma^5\}=0$$

Comment: @Fluctuations no, it is not true. But for every matrix $x$ (in your case, $x=i\gamma^5$), the following holds:

$$ \left[ x, \exp x \right] = 0 $$

Comment: Hindsight did most of the follow-up job for me, so thanks. Regarding the last point, @Fluctuations, as Hindsight already mentioned, they don't anticommute, they commute! To see this explicitly, expand the exponential in $$ \[ x, \exp x \]$$ and exploit the linearity $$ \[ x, (y+z) \] = \[ x, y \] + \[ x, z \]$$. Clearly, $x$ commutes with identity, with $x$, with $x^2$, and so on. :)

Comment: And @Hindsight, thanks for the follow-up job. Yes, chiral symmetry holds only in the $m=0$ limit. Finite mass _explicitly_ breaks chiral symmetry. But if these mass terms are small, like $u$ and $d$ quarks (the $SU(2)$ case), chiral symmetry can be considered an approximate symmetry of the strong interactions. :)

Comment: @Hindsight Does it matter wether the 5 is an upper index or a lower index on the gamma matrix? Because I went sloppy in my comment and misplaced the index, instead f placing it downstairs being it raised to an exponential, I placed it accidentally upstairs

Comment: @Fluctuations there is no such thing as $\gamma_5$.

Comment: If you see in the question it is written as such in the exponential.. Why isn't there $\gamma_5$ I read in Zee's book that it doesn't matter when you flip the index of pauli matrices but it does matter when you flip those of gamma matrices. Did I miss sth?

Comment: @Fluctuations - AFAIK, if you use (as usual) metric tensor to toggle between covariant and contravariant versions of the gamma matrices, $\gamma^{\mu} = g^{\mu \nu} \gamma_{\nu}$, then, using the metric $(+,-,-,-)$, you get $\gamma^0 = \gamma_0$ and $\gamma^i = -\gamma_i$, where the index $i = 1, 2, 3$ and doesn't cover $0$. Using this seems to give me $\gamma^5 = - \gamma_5$. So, I'll ping Hindsight, and repeat "_Did I miss something?_" :)

Comment: @Hindsight - Please read the above comment and correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Fluctuations - But I think, the point is - define your $\gamma^5$ when you get started itself. Either $\gamma^5$ or $\gamma_5$. But it is advisable not to toggle between them in the middle of the calculation, because that may lead to confusion.

Comment: Some extra (related) info - Josh's answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/101240) seems to support the reasoning of my [above comment](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144397/how-to-know-if-the-pseudoscalar-yukawa-lagrangian-is-invariant-under-chiral-tran/144414#comment300612_144414). Again, did I miss something?