# Index manipulation of Dirac matrices

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, covariance, dirac-matrices

In several places I see that Dirac matrix indexes are treated as usual 4-vector indexes that can be changed with the metric tensor, for example
$$\gamma_\mu=g_{\mu\nu} \gamma^\nu. $$  Why is it true?

Comment: Question already answered here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101234/

Comment: Actually I couldn't find an explanation why this is true.

Comment: They need to transform like that so that the Dirac equation is covariant. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation#Covariant_form_and_relativistic_invariance

Answer (score 0):

The equation that defines the gamma matrices is
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\gamma_\mu \gamma_\nu + \gamma_\nu \gamma_\mu\right) = \eta_{\mu\nu}
$$
This is a symmetric (dot) product between the gamma matrices which generates the metric tensor of Minkowski space. In general, we can come up with a set of gamma matrices for any pseudo-Riemannian manifold. For ordinary 3D space, these are the Pauli matrices.

However, if we focus on the *geometry* described by the gamma matrices, we get a more complete picture of what's going on. In particular: what does the product of two gamma matrices, $\gamma_\mu \gamma_\nu$, mean? If we assume an orthonormal basis (for convenience), the off-diagonal elements of $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ will be zero, so the symmetric product is zero. But what about the antisymmetric (wedge product?) The defining equation implies that $\gamma_\mu \gamma_\nu = -\gamma_\nu \gamma_\mu$ when $\mu \neq \nu$, and it turns out elements of this form describe *oriented areas* - known as *bivectors*. In fact, you can take antisymmetric products of 3 or 4 gammas and you get *trivectors* (3-vectors) and *tetravectors* (4-vectors). (In an $n$-dimensional space, you can't go above $n$-vectors, and all further antisymmetric products are zero). The set of all possible antisymmetric products of gammas - scalars, vectors, bivectors, trivectors, tetravectors in 3+1D space - generate the [spacetime algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime_algebra), $\text{Cl}_{1,3}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ (or $\text{Cl}_{3,1}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ if you prefer the alternate signature).

The key takeaway here is that the gammas aren't supposed to be treated like matrices. Rather, *they are a matrix representation of the basis vectors of spacetime that encodes their transformation properties.* Those transformation properties include the construction of bivectors, trivectors, and tetravectors as well as linear combinations of all of these types of elements.